# How To put Button into Tabs

Tags: html, css

I have created some HTML and CSS code

I have 3 main tabs(Lights,Kitchen,Others) and as I write this code in the Lights main tab I want two Other tabs that names of these tabs are Room1 and Room2 
and in this code I have some buttons in each main tabs but since I create the tabs Room1 and Room2 ,,the keys :LTurnOn and LTurnOff (for tab Room1)  and CTurnOn and CTurnOff(for tab Room2)  are disappeared.

How can I fix this?

And I have to say that I want when I click on Room1 the two keys for tab only appear and so on Room2 Tab

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-top: none;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    background: #90EE90;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 300%;
    padding-left: 350%;
    margin-left: -20px!important;
    margin-top: -120%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s
}

.button:active:after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0s
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/New-Age-4K-Abstract-Wallpapers.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Lights')">Lights</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Kitchen')">Kitchen</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Other')">Other</button>
</div>



<div id="Lights" class="tabcontent">
<div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Room1')">Room1</button>
</div>
<div id="Room1" class="tabcontent">
<form>
  Turn On:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="LTurn On" >
  <br>
  Turn Off:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="LTurn Off">
</form>
</div>
<div class="tab">
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Room2')">Room2</button>
</div>
<div id="Room2" class="tabcontent">
<form>
  Turn On:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="CTurn On" >
  <br>
  Turn Off:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="CTurn Off">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Kitchen" class="tabcontent">
<form>
  Turn On:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="KTurn On">
  <br>
  Turn Off:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="KTurn Off">
</form>

</div>

<div id="Other" class="tabcontent">
<form>
  Turn On:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="OTurn On">
  <br>
  Turn Off:<br>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="OTurn Off">
</form>

</div>
<div class="bg"></div>

<script>
function Tools(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want it like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }
    /* Style the tab */
    
    div.tab {
      overflow: hidden;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
    
    div.tab button {
      background-color: inherit;
      float: left;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
    
    div.tab button:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    /* Create an active/current tablink class */
    
    div.tab button.active {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    /* Style the tab content */
    
    .tabcontent {
      display: none;
      padding: 6px 12px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      border-top: none;
    }
    
    .button {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #000000;
      border: none;
      font-size: 28px;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
      /* Safari */
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      text-decoration: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .button:after {
      content: "";
      background: #90EE90;
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      padding-top: 300%;
      padding-left: 350%;
      margin-left: -20px!important;
      margin-top: -120%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.8s
    }
    
    .button:active:after {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: 0s
    }
    
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .bg {
      /* The image used */
      background-image: url("http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/New-Age-4K-Abstract-Wallpapers.jpg");
      /* Full height */
      height: 100%;
      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Lights')">Lights</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Kitchen')">Kitchen</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Other')">Other</button>
  </div>



  <div id="Lights" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Room1')">Room1</button>
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="Tools(event, 'Room2')">Room2</button>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="Room1" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="LTurn On">
      <br> Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="LTurn Off">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Room2" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="CTurn On">
      <br> Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="CTurn Off">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Kitchen" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="KTurn On">
      <br> Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="KTurn Off">
    </form>

  </div>

  <div id="Other" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="OTurn On">
      <br> Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="OTurn Off">
    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="bg"></div>

  <script>
    function Tools(evt, cityName) {
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

If yes, the problem is that you've created the divs `Room1` and `Room2` inside of `Lights`. With the click on the button which triggers `Tools()`, it will remove the `active` from `Lights` and the content will be `display: none`.

My fixed example is one solution how you could solve it. I just moved the `<div id="Room1" class="tabcontent">` and `<div id="Room2" class="tabcontent">` out of `<div id="Lights" class="tabcontent">` and it worked.

If you don't want to move the `div` out of `Lights`, you only have to fix your JS to avoid that the JS will `display: none` if you click the button which is inside of `Lights`.

Comment: Oh thanks Patrick that is exactly what i want   and One more question can I design the tab to when I click the tabs the back ground display under the tab as you see now this is white when I click the tabs I want that the tabs include wallpaper

Comment: You want that the tabcontent has the wallpaper as background? You could just add `bg` to all classes like `class="tabcontent bg"` or add `.tabcontent,` to `.bg` in your style. This would look like this: `.tabcontent, .bg { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

why so confusing you already give the name as kitchen and why again give room it make complex use names like hall,kitchen,bedroom so you no need to give room1 or room2 and in lights you can combo box to lights off ,lights on

Comment: I dont know that because i am learning the HTML right now and I have another question:can I design the tab to when I click the tabs the back ground display under the tab as you see now this is white when I click the tabs I want that the tabs include wallpaper????

Answer (score 0):

here you go! I added a data-city to the buttons and edited your javascript a little bit :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

        /* Style the tab */
        div.tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        /* Style the buttons inside the tab */
        div.tab button {
            background-color: inherit;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 17px;
        }

        /* Change background color of buttons on hover */
        div.tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

        /* Create an active/current tablink class */
        div.tab button.active {
          background-color: #ccc;
      }

      /* Style the tab content */
      .tabcontent {
        display: none;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        border-top: none;
    }

    .button {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #000000;
        border: none;
        font-size: 28px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
        text-decoration: none;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .button:after {
        content: "";
        background: #90EE90;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 300%;
        padding-left: 350%;
        margin-left: -20px!important;
        margin-top: -120%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.8s
    }

    .button:active:after {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0s
    }

    body, html {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .bg {
        /* The image used */
        background-image: url("http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/New-Age-4K-Abstract-Wallpapers.jpg");

        /* Full height */
        height: 100%; 

        /* Center and scale the image nicely */
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>


    <div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" data-city="Lights" onclick="Tools(event)">Lights</button>
      <button class="tablinks" data-city="Kitchen" onclick="Tools(event)">Kitchen</button>
      <button class="tablinks" data-city="Other" onclick="Tools(event)">Other</button>
    </div>



<div id="Lights" class="tabcontent">
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" data-city="Room1" onclick="Tools(event)">Room1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Room1" class="tabcontent">
        <form>
            Turn On:<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="LTurn On" >
            <br>
            Turn Off:<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="LTurn Off">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" data-city="Room2" onclick="Tools(event)">Room2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="Room2" class="tabcontent">
        <form>
            Turn On:<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="CTurn On" >
            <br>
            Turn Off:<br>
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="CTurn Off">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Kitchen" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="KTurn On">
      <br>
      Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="KTurn Off">
  </form>

</div>

<div id="Other" class="tabcontent">
    <form>
      Turn On:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn On" value="OTurn On">
      <br>
      Turn Off:<br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="Turn Off" value="OTurn Off">
  </form>

</div>
<div class="bg"></div>

<script>
    function Tools(evt){
        var city = evt.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-city');
        var parent = evt.currentTarget.parentElement;
        var tabcontent = parent.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for(i=0;i< tabcontent.length;i++){
            tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
            tabcontent[i].className="tabcontent";
            tablinks[i].className="tablinks";

        }
        tabcontent[city].style.display = 'block';
        tabcontent[city].className += " active";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
        
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```